# Invalid data after declaration in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I don't understand why I have this type of error when I run my code. I've checked this several times and everything seems to be good, still the code does not want to run.

Here's my `__main__.py` file :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty  # at top of file

class AccountDetailsForm(AnchorLayout):

    server_box = ObjectProperty()
    username_box = ObjectProperty()
    password_box = ObjectProperty()

    def login(self):
        print(self.server_box.text)
        print(self.username_box.text)
        print(self.password_box.text)


class Orkiv(App):
    pass

Orkiv().run()
```

And here's my `orkiv.kv` file :

```
AccountDetailsForm:

<AccountDetailsForm>:
    anchor_y: "top"
    server_box: server_input
    username_box: username_input
    password_box: password_input

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        height: "200dp"
        size_hint_y: None

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            row_default_height: "40dp"
            row_force_default: True
            spacing: "10dp"
            padding: "10dp"
        Label:
            text: "Server" //THE ERROR SEEMS TO HAPPEN HERE
        AccountDetailsTextInput:
            id: server_input
        Label:
            text: "Username"
        AccountDetailsTextInput:
            id: username_input
        Label:
            text: "Password"
        AccountDetailsTextInput:
            password: True
            id: password_input

    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "40dp"
        text: "Login"
        on_press: root.login()
```

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: unrelated, but the usual name for your main Kivy file is main.py, not \_\_main\_\_.py. Sub-projects like python-for-android expect it to be named main.py.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `orkiv.kv` file, change `AccountDetailsTextInput` to just `TextInput`.

```
AccountDetailsForm:

<AccountDetailsForm>:

    anchor_y: "top"
    server_box: server_input
    username_box: username_input
    password_box: password_input

    BoxLayout:

        orientation: "vertical"
        height: "200dp"
        size_hint_y: None

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            row_default_height: "40dp"
            row_force_default: True
            spacing: "10dp"
            padding: "10dp"

        Label:
            text: "Server"

        TextInput:
            id: server_input

        Label:
            text: "Username"

        TextInput:
            id: username_input

        Label:
            text: "Password"

        TextInput:
            password: True
            id: password_input

    Button:

        size_hint_y: None
        height: "40dp"
        text: "Login"
        on_press: root.login()
```

The app should run. See my output below.

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Actually in the http://archlinux.me/dusty/2013/06/29/creating-an-application-in-kivy-part-3/ tutorial, it is `TextInput` like you said, but I have this error with both solutions. That is strange, we have the same exact files and I have an error but you don't... I can't figure out why.

Comment: Hm. The error stopped after changing it to `TextInput` for me. Can you post the exact traceback? I'm thinking it should be no different from mine though. Have you tried copying the above exactly? Long shot, but the spacing might be shot as well.

Comment: Well it worked !! I've copied your answer into my code and it worked. That is very strange.

Comment: Has to be the spacing, then. Can't explain it anymore than that. Also, if your comment `//THE ERROR SEEMS TO HAPPEN HERE` is part of the file while running, well... It's not the proper way to comment. Just putting it out there as it might have contributed. There were a couple of whitespaces here and there and I just cleaned it up, lol. :) Thanks for accepting and good luck!

Comment: Yep the comment is not in my code, I've just added there to let you know where does the error happen in my code.

Comment: Then it is weird. I sincerely hope it's not the spacing, though. But at least it works! :D

Answer (score 0):

According to kivy module documentation, if you want to provide a box for editable plain text use the class "TextInput".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).